# Slider will not slide up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, comparison

This is the code for a left-right slider comparison.

**Can anyone help me make it work from top to bottom?**

I have it working going from left to right but I need it to go from top to bottom.

I tried to make some changes, but with no result.
This is a [slider](https://codepen.io/bamf/pen/jEpxOX) from Codepen.

```js
// Call & init
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ba-slider').each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    // Adjust the slider
    var width = cur.width() + 'px';
    cur.find('.resize img').css('width', width);
    // Bind dragging events
    drags(cur.find('.handle'), cur.find('.resize'), cur);
  });
});

// Update sliders on resize. 
// Because we all do this: i.imgur.com/YkbaV.gif
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.ba-slider').each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    var width = cur.width() + 'px';
    cur.find('.resize img').css('width', width);
  });
});

function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container) {

  // Initialize the dragging event on mousedown.
  dragElement.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {

    dragElement.addClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.addClass('resizable');

    // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
    var startX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    // Get the initial position
    var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
      posX = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - startX,
      containerOffset = container.offset().left,
      containerWidth = container.outerWidth();

    // Set limits
    var minLeft = containerOffset + 10;
    var maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10;

    // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
    dragElement.parents().on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {

      // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
      var moveX = (e.pageX) ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      var leftValue = moveX + posX - dragWidth;

      // Prevent going off limits
      if (leftValue < minLeft) {
        leftValue = minLeft;
      } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
        leftValue = maxLeft;
      }

      // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs width.
      var widthValue = (leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) * 100 / containerWidth + '%';

      // Set the new values for the slider and the handle. 
      // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
      $('.draggable').css('left', widthValue).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
      });
      $('.resizable').css('width', widthValue);
    }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function() {
      dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(e) {
    dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
  });
}
```

```css
.ba-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ba-slider img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.resize {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.handle {
  /* Thin line seperator */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 4px;
  margin-left: -2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.handle:after {
  /* Big orange knob  */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: -32px 0 0 -32px;
  content: '\21d4';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 64px;
  background: #ffb800;
  /* @orange */
  border: 1px solid #e6a600;
  /* darken(@orange, 5%) */
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 60px 50px -30px #ffd466;
  /* lighten(@orange, 20%)*/
}

.draggable:after {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: -24px 0 0 -24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ba-slider">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9JWNlfH.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="resize">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GS86OpZ.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <span class="handle"></span>
</div>
```

js +css-code is on codepen..I could not load it here( sorry)

Comment: The images don't work here because the assets don't support https

Comment: you can access la link. Thank you for your help!. https://codepen.io/bamf/pen/jEpxOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shouldn't really have done this because it was a coding change not a coding issue, but I was interested in the how to do it.

I have changed all the width calculations to heights and all the positions from left to top. I also made similar adjustments to the CSS.

```js
// Call & init
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ba-slider').each(function(){
    var cur = $(this);
    // Adjust the slider
    var height = cur.height()+'px';
    cur.find('.resize img').css('height', height);
    // Bind dragging events
    drags(cur.find('.handle'), cur.find('.resize'), cur);
  });
});

// Update sliders on resize. 
// Because we all do this: i.imgur.com/YkbaV.gif
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.ba-slider').each(function(){
    var cur = $(this);
    var height = cur.height()+'px';
    cur.find('.resize img').css('height', height);
  });
});

function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container) {
 
  // Initialize the dragging event on mousedown.
  dragElement.on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    
    dragElement.addClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.addClass('resizable');
    
    // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
    var startY = (e.pageY) ? e.pageY : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    
    // Get the initial position
    var dragHeight = dragElement.outerHeight(),
        posY = dragElement.offset().top + dragHeight - startY,
        containerOffset = container.offset().top,
        containerHeight = container.outerHeight();
 
    // Set limits
    minTop = containerOffset + 10;
    maxTop = containerOffset + containerHeight - dragHeight - 10;
    
    // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
    dragElement.parents().on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
     
      // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
      var moveY = (e.pageY) ? e.pageY : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
      
      topValue = moveY + posY - dragHeight;
      
      // Prevent going off limits
      if ( topValue < minTop) {
        topValue = minTop;
      } else if (topValue > maxTop) {
        topValue = maxTop;
      }
      
      // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs height.
      heightValue = (topValue + dragHeight/2 - containerOffset)*100/containerHeight+'%';
   
      // Set the new values for the slider and the handle. 
      // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
      $('.draggable').css('top', heightValue).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
      });
      $('.resizable').css('height', heightValue);
    }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(){
      dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', function(e){
    dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
    resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
  });
}
```

```css
.ba-slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.ba-slider img {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
 
.resize {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.handle { /* Thin line seperator */
  position:absolute; 
  left:0;
  top:50%;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:4px;
  margin-left:-2px;
 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
 
.handle:after {  /* Big orange knob  */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: -32px 0 0 -32px;
 
    content:'\21D5';
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:36px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:64px;
 
    background: #ffb800; /* @orange */
    border:1px solid #e6a600; /* darken(@orange, 5%) */
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow:
      0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 
      inset 0 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5),
      inset 0 60px 50px -30px #ffd466; /* lighten(@orange, 20%)*/ 
}

.draggable:after {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: -24px 0 0 -24px;
    line-height:48px;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ba-slider">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" alt="">       
  <div class="resize">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" alt="">
  </div>
  <span class="handle"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you are very smart.